# Max value of Xmx and Xms in SpringToolSuite4

Tags: spring-tool-suite, sts

What is the max memory size in `SpringToolSuite4.ini` for `STS` for the following parameters?

1. -Xms
2. -Xmx

are the above parameters customized, if yes how much size we can increase for both?

Comment: Would this depend on the amount of memory on the machine STS is running on?

Comment: approximately how much size we can?

Comment: usually it's not recommended to set heap size to more than 50% of your memory. But if you're running other Java programs on your computer then you should try a lower number. That being said, when I used to use STS I set it to 50% because it was the most memory intensive application on my computer